# Create one-to-one association in transaction

Tags: go, associations, go-gorm

UserService.go

```
func (service UserService) Create(model *models.User) (*models.User, error) {
    db, err := database.GetConnection()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    tx := db.Begin()
    if tx.Error != nil {
        fmt.Errorf("%v", err)
        return nil, err
    }
    if err := tx.Create(model).Error; err != nil {
        fmt.Errorf("%v", err)
        tx.Rollback()
        return nil, err
    }
    if err := tx.Save(model).Error; err != nil {
        fmt.Errorf("%v", err)
        tx.Rollback()
        return nil, err
    }
    if err := service.UserProfileService.Create(tx, model); err != nil {
        fmt.Errorf("%v", err)
        tx.Rollback()
        return nil, err
    }
    if err := tx.Commit().Error; err != nil {
        fmt.Errorf("%v", err)
        return nil, err
    }
    return model, nil
}
```

UserProfileService.go

```
func (UserProfileService) Create(tx *gorm.DB, user *models.User) error {
    if err := tx.Create(models.UserProfile{User: user}).Error; err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}
```

User.go

```
type User struct {
    Id               *uuid.UUID     `json:"id" gorm:"not null;primary_key;type:uuid;default:uuid_generate_v4();"`
    Name             *string        `json:"name" gorm:"not null;type:varchar(255);"`
    CreatedAt        time.Time      `json:"createdAt" gorm:"type:timestamp;default:now()"`
    UpdatedAt        time.Time      `json:"updatedAt" gorm:"type:timestamp;default:now()"`
    DeletedAt        *time.Time     `json:"deleteAt,omitempty" gorm:"type:timestamp;"`
}

func (User) TableName() string {
    return "users"
}
```

UserProfile.go

```
type UserProfile struct {
    User        *User      `json:"id" gorm:"not null;primary_key;foreignkey:Id;type:uuid;default:uuid_generate_v4();"`
    Id          *uuid.UUID `json:"id" gorm:"not null;type:uuid"`
    Description string     `json:"description" gorm:"not null;type:varchar(255)"`
    UpdatedAt   time.Time  `json:"updatedAt" gorm:"type:timestamp;default:now()"`
}

func (UserProfile) TableName() string {
    return "users_profile"
}
```

So, every User must have just one UserProfile, that is why UserProfile's primary key is also a foreign key (User (id)). But when I try to make a request, I got this error: `(using unaddressable value)`

Any ideas on how to get this working?

Comment: I'm guessing but maybe in your `UserProfileService` `Create` method probably you  should provide model.UserProfile as a pointer?

Answer (score 0):

The model that you are inserting in UserProfileService.go is not a pointer, which is why you are getting the `unaddressable` error.

```
func (UserProfileService) Create(tx *gorm.DB, user *models.User) error {
    if err := tx.Create(*models.UserProfile{User: user}).Error; err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}
```

That referencing in the `tx.Create` call will most likely fix your error. If not please post the full error.